# Linking Javascript code in external file to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is already working thanks to Brian but still when I put it on an external file it doesn't work. Can anyone help me understand why?

js code (the other functions are ok, didn't put it here because the code would be too long):

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var files = evt.target.files;

    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
        f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
        f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a','</li>');
    }

    $("#list").html('<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>');    
 }


$(document).ready(function() {

    //showAllImages();
    //showAllImagesFromCategory("beach");
    styleWordCloud();


    //associar pesquisa de categoria a cada palavra da nuvem de palavras
    $( "nav ul li a" ).each(function( index ) {


        $(this).click( function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            clearResults();

            showAllImagesFromCategory( $(this).text() );

        });

    });


    $("#search_form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var q = $("#query").val()

        clearResults();
        showAllImagesFromQuery( q );

     });

    $( "div.color" ).each(function( index ) {

        $(this).click( function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var selectedColor = $(this).css("background-color");
            //alert( selectedColor );
            clearResults();
            showAllImagesNearDominantColor( selectedColor );

        });

    });

    $( "#files" ).change(handleFileSelect(event));

});
```

html code:

```
<head>
<title>Pesquisa de Imagens</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<!-- Inclusao de biblioteca JQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="js/XML_LStorage.js"></script>
<script src="js/jsCode.js" language="javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_style.css">


</head>

<body>

<!--zona do cabeçalho da página. Inclui logotipo e barra de navegacao-->
<header>        
    <h1 id="site_title"><a href="index.html">Pesquisa de Imagens</a></h1>


    <!-- Main Menu -->
    <h2>Main menu</h2>
    <nav class="main-navigation">
        <ol>
            <li><a class="menu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu" href="search_bar.html">Barra Pesquisa</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu" href="color_search.html">Pesquisa por cor dominante</a></li>
            <li class="current"><a class="menu" href="image_search.html">Pesquisa por imagens</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu" href="contact_us.html">Contacte-nos</a></li>
        </ol>
</nav>



</header>

<!-- zona de conteúdo da página. Inclui logotipo e barra de navegacao -->
<article>
    <nav class="cloud">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">beach</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">birthday</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">face</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">indoor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">manmade</a></li> <!-- alterar para todos de uma maneira bacana -->
            <li><a href="#">marriage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">nature</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">no people</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">outdoor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">party</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">people</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">snow</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>

    <!-- Primeira secção -->
    <section class="search_bar">

        <h2>Pesquisa por imagens</h2>
        <p>Pesquisa por pastas</p>
        <form id="img_search">
            <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple/>
            <output id="list"></output>
        </form>
        <p>Ou arrasta a imagem para o quadrado a tracejado</p>
        <center>
        <div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
        <output id="list_dropzone"></output></center>

    </section>          

</article>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the browser developer tools. Does the JS console show any errors? Does the Net tab show the JS file being loaded successfully with a `200 OK` status and the right content-type?

Comment: Your HTML is a weird hybrid of HTML 3.2 and HTML 5. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: also missing doctype

Comment: @Quentin what are you on about. Add `<!DOCTYPE html><html>` and remove language/center and it validates to HTML5

Comment: @mplungjan He's talking about `language="javascript"` at the very least. This particular method has been deprecated. In `HTML5`, the `type` operator is optional, but the `language` operator is deprecated.

Comment: @mplungjan No reason to get snarky. Everyone's here to learn.

Comment: Still irrelevant to the problem at hand. What is styleWordCloud?
Please add your scripts to http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/v14grr7u/

Comment: the hole code is now here http://jsfiddle.net/v14grr7u/1/
I had the <!DOCTYPE html><html> just didn't copy and pasted it I thought it wasn't necessary, my bad. @Quentin I guess it has some erros since it doesn't show a 200 ok status

Comment: @Alexandra — Not showing a 200 OK doesn't mean the JS has errors in it. What status code does it show?

Comment: The option getUserData() or setUserData() was discontinued. In alternative, use WeakMap or element.dataset. requestNotifier.js:63
OpenGL compositor Initialized Succesfully.
Version: 2.1 INTEL-8.28.30
Vendor: Intel Inc.
Renderer: Intel HD Graphics 4000 OpenGL Engine
FBO Texture Target: TEXTURE_2D

Comment: @Alexandra Which status code is returned when you load the script? Can you see it as a source in your browser dev tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line-

```
$( "#files" ).change(handleFileSelect(event));
```

To-

```
$("#files").on("change", handleFileSelect); // See http://api.jquery.com/on/
```

Or-

```
$("#files").change(handleFileSelect); // See http://api.jquery.com/change/
```

By writing "handleFileSelect(event)" you are executing the function immediately, rather than in response to the event (the brackets pass a undefined parameter named "event" to the function and execute it straight away). jQuery will automatically pass an event object as the first parameter to the event handler you define.

As evt is undefined, files is undefined within the function - which is causing an error.

For reference, if you want to pass parameters to the event you could do this-

```
$("#files").on("change",  function (event) { handleFileSelect(event, someParameter); });
```

Comment: @Alexandra I have forked your jsFiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/qztzzwgj/1/ and the JavaScript error has gone away. What do you mean by not working? What is it supposed to do that it isn't?